# Incorrect data returned when querying FB Graph API for a URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I query the FB Graph to get the share count for particular URLs, but in some cases the incorrect data is returned.

Here's an example:

The code I use in the test file:

```
$obj_fb = json_decode( @file_get_contents( 'http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://news.therawfoodworld.com/paraplegics-can-now-buy-robotic-legs/' ) );
var_dump($obj_fb);
```

Now... on one server, here is what I get (which is incorrect):
http://news.therawfoodworld.com/test.php (view test2.php in the same location for phpinfo)

On another... it works as expected (exact same code for both tests): http://www.therawfoodworld.com/images/test.php (view test2.php in the same location for phpinfo)

Running the same in a browser works as expected as well.

What could it be about this one server that generates the incorrect data? I mean... the data is *valid* but unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

I used localhost and Zend Server to see the output of the code

And json_decode() of this gives the JSON object of this which is:

> object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["id"]=> string(69) "http://news.therawfoodworld.com/paraplegics-can-now-buy-robotic-legs/" ["shares"]=> int(3) }

Both the servers give me this output, http://news.theraw............. I guess the output from server 1 is correct. Both the servers are hosted servers, I mean not localhost or zend like servers??

> I answered because I could not comment.